# Value in the cell but need a text to be displayed

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

The cell should show 1M (1 month) and have the value of 30 (days) for computation. 
What is the best way to do so?

I typed in the cell 1M and then went to

> Home-> Conditional Formating-> New rule-> Format only cells that
>   contain -> Format only cells with SPECIFIC TEXT containing =A2=30.
>   Then I clicked on FORMAT-> Number-> Custom-> General-> OK-> OK

...but it doesn't change anything.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to change your approach slightly; Keep the value on screen as 1M,  but when your code references that cell, stick in an if else statement to be able to consume days.

```
=IF(A1="1M", "30",)
```

Answer (score 0):

For values up to 360 you can do it the other way round. Enter the number value into the cell, e.g.

```
30
60
90
etc.
```

and format the cells with custom format

```
m\M
```

This will display as

```
1M
2M
3M
etc
```